# Flutter timeout during test loading expect --timeout none

Tags: flutter, dart, testing, timeout, github-actions

I am trying to run my integration tests with github actions, but somehow they always timeout before they even start. I tried increasing the timeout limit and setting it none, but after 12 min the test always aborts. This is the part of the action file responsible for creating the emulator and starting the test:

```yaml
- name: Launch iOS Simulator
  uses: futureware-tech/simulator-action@v1
  with:
    model: 'iPhone 13'

- name: Integration tests
  run: flutter test -r expanded --timeout none integration_test/run_all_test.dart
```

And this is the log from the Integration tests part:

```
Run flutter test -r expanded --dart-define "DEP_ENV=test" --timeout none integration_test/run_all_test.dart
Running pod install...                                            282.6s
Running Xcode build...                                          00:00 +0 -1: loading /Users/runner/work/name-app/name-app/integration_test/run_all_test.dart [E]
  TimeoutException after 0:12:00.000000: Test timed out after 12 minutes.
  package:test_api/src/backend/invoker.dart 333:28  Invoker._handleError.<fn>
  dart:async/zone.dart 1418:47                      _rootRun
  dart:async/zone.dart 1328:19                      _CustomZone.run
  package:test_api/src/backend/invoker.dart 331:10  Invoker._handleError
  package:test_api/src/backend/invoker.dart 287:9   Invoker.heartbeat.<fn>.<fn>
  dart:async/zone.dart 1426:13                      _rootRun
  dart:async/zone.dart 1328:19                      _CustomZone.run
  package:test_api/src/backend/invoker.dart 286:38  Invoker.heartbeat.<fn>
  dart:async-patch/timer_patch.dart 18:15           Timer._createTimer.<fn>
  dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart 395:19         _Timer._runTimers
  dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart 426:5          _Timer._handleMessage
  dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart 192:12      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage
  
00:00 +0 -1: Some tests failed.
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I think that somehow the test also includes the build time for the timeout, because the entire `Integration tests` part runs only 13 min. And a clean build on my computer also sometimes takes up to 10 min :(

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a way to change the 12 minute timeout, but by running `pod install` before starting the build for the test, the build time is cut in half and therefore the timeout is not a problem any more. These are the changes I made to the yml file:

```yaml
- name: Launch iOS Simulator
  uses: futureware-tech/simulator-action@v1
  with:
    model: 'iPhone 13'

- name: Pod Install
  run: |
    cd ios
    pod install
    cd ..

- name: Integration tests
  run: flutter test -r expanded --timeout none integration_test/run_all_test.dart
```